# Extract information using sed regex

Tags: linux, sed

I am using sed regex to extract some information from a log file in order to use it further for analysis. I created a below command but it wont works for me.

`sed -e 's/\([0-9] [0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*\)[^@]* ([^@]*@[^[:spa
ce:]]*).*F=<\([^ ]*\)>.*I=[\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.)].*$/\1\t\2/' logs`

Logs:

```
2017-02-13 10:31:55 1cd9Ev-003XiE-Sx ** rwackow@sjmcpk.org F=<ceo@ccp.com.in> R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp H=ah2.inboundmx.com [216.82.242.115] I=[147.75.228.64] X=TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec.cloud CN=mail132.messagelabs.com": SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 553-Message filtered. Refer to the Troubleshooting page at\n553-http://www.symanteccloud.com/troubleshooting for more\n553 information. (#5.7.1)

2017-02-14 10:01:40 1cd9Ev-003XiE-Sx ** solowki@pknic.com.in F=<ceo@ccffp.org> R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp H=ah2.inboundmx.com [216.82.242.115] I=[14.176.22.221] X=TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec.cloud CN=mail132.messagelabs.com": 501 Connection rejected by policy. Refer to the Troubleshooting page at\n501-http://www.symanteccloud.com/troubleshooting for more\n501 information. (#5.7.1)
```

I wanted to extract the following fields from above logs:

```
Timestamp            EmailTo:           EmailFrom:      IPAddress:      ErrorCodes:
2017-02-13 10:31:55 rwackow@sjmcpk.org  ceo@ccp.com.in  147.75.228.64   553
2017-02-14 10:01:40 solowki@pknic.com.in ceo@ccffp.org  14.176.22.221   501
```

Comment: yeah,  run `awk '{t=$0;sub(/.*\\n/, "", t);sub(/ .*/, "", t);print $1, $2, $5, substr($6, 4, length($6)-4), substr($11, 4, length($11)-4), t}'`  ... the `t, sub, sub` extracts the error code, the rest is self-explanatory - print the respective fields except for `$6` and `$11` where it extracts only part of the field and prints the result

Comment: I am not having any other answer except thanking you. If you don't mind let me know how can i master in awk and sed ?

Comment: well, read the manuals (both gnu sed and gnu awk manuals can be downloaded as _pdf_) & practice at the same time; just like with anything else in life, you have to crawl before you walk :) ... so start with simple tasks and work your way up as your skills improve

Comment: Great food for thought :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other idea instead of extracting fields needed is to remove extra:

```
sed '
    s/[^: ]*\s\*\*\s//
    s/F=<//
    s/>.*I=\[/ /
    s/\].*more\\n/ /
    s/\sinf.*//
    ' log.file
```

- first command remove `1cd9Ev-003XiE-Sx **`
- second — `F=<`
- third — `> R=dkim_lookuphost T=dkim_remote_smtp H=ah2.inboundmx.com [216.82.242.115] I=[`

and so on…

Comment: thanks its working, can you explain a lil bit ?

Comment: @rlinux57 I do not understand which further explanation needed but here you are.